# How to generate random number without seed?

Tags: ada

Im try to find the equivalent of `rand()` which generates a random number between 0 and 1 without a seed. Could someone show me how this can be achieved in ADA?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Ada.Numerics.Float_Random](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rm/html/RM-A-5-2.html#I6094).

```
G : Ada.Numerics.Float_Random.Generator;
R : Ada.Numerics.Float_Random.Uniformly_Distributed;

-- Get a random number
R := Ada.Numerics.Float_Random.Random(G);
```

Comment: I believe technically both this and rand() do use a seed : in this case, a default seed provided by the runtime system, yes?

Comment: @Brian, the description of the [Reset](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rm/html/RM-A-5-2.html#p34) procedures mentions there being a _time-dependent_ reset if no "initiator" (which I read as "seed") is specified. So my guess is that the initial seed comes off the clock.